# Suggesting a form of the equation of the given curve

Tags: limits, functions, asymptotics, curves, regression

I am really struggling with this problem for a long time.

I think it is easy to understand, but difficult to solve;

We have a curve that has a lower limit as $x \rightarrow -\infty$, and it has another lower limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$. This curve increases only before the peak and decreases only after the peak. The rate at which this curve increases may not be the same rate at which this curve decreases (apart from the sign). What I mean is: the function may increases rapidly but decreases slowly, or vice versa.

Also, it is ***not*** a piecewise function. Moreover, it should be integerable at any domain.

---

If the form of that function contains something like this: $ae^{-x^2}$ (Gaussian Distribution), then it will not be integerable.

I was trying to combine two expression (piecewise) to make it (not piecewise), but no luck: like combining

$y=a-be^{cx}$ for $-\infty <x \le j$, and $y=A-Be^{Cx}$ for $j < x < \infty$; where $a,b,c,A,B,C,j$ are constants.

---

The following curve is plotted (using piecewise function) just to illustrate the problem.

[image]

---

So the goal is to find the form of the equation of the curve with the following criteria:

- has a lower limit before the peak.
- has another lower limit after the peak.
- The rate of increasing may be different from the rate of decreasing (apart from the sign).
- Must be integerable in any domain.
- Must not be a piecewise function.

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Do you mean integrable with an analytical closed-form ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I do mean that. (Math Keeps Me Busy) suggestion is really good. If you have any other suggestion, please share it. Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: adding a sigmoid (say $a\arctan x+b$) allows you to absorb the "step". Then you can focus on a function decaying to the $x$ axis, which is easier.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari. Suggestion: Combine the two functions $y=a+be^{cx}$ and $y=A+Be^{Cx}$ with a continuous function of logistic kind (or other similar function). For example see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are many functions which satisfy your requirements. Perhaps there are more requirements that you have not stated? One solution to the problem as stated is

$$y=a+b\frac{\frac{x}{c}}{\sqrt{(\frac{x}{c})^2+1}}+d^2\frac{1}{(\frac{x}{c})^2+1}$$
It has a lower limit both before and after the peak, and it is smooth, both integrable, and not "piecewise".

You may play around with the parameterized function at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o0ja1e0c0o

Comment: Dear what I want is a function where I can fix the lower limits, I can fix the rate in which the function increases and decreases, I can fix the position of the peak. The function you suggested has no enough parameters to fix the shape of the curve. For example: suggest me a function with the same criteria but has $1$ as the lower limit before the peak, and has $3$ as the peak is at the point $(2,7)$, also increases slowly and decreases rapidly. in that case, you should involve parameters $a,b,c,d,...$ to your function. Hope you get my point.

Comment: OK. thank you for the clarification. You can build up a function by adding together shifted versions of this function, plus another function. I will explain in the reply.

Comment: I have edited the answer to give you a parameterized function that gives you quite a variety of options. You can play with the function at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bgsa5kstog

Comment: You are good!. I believe you can again manipulate it. You are almost there. your function has a disadvantage. In my OP, I mentioned that the function increases (ONLY) before the peak, so it should increases whatever the values of the parameters $a,b,c,f$ I put. Similarly it should be decreasing (ONLY) after the peak. Your suggestion is really appreciated, but I need the "only" to have a place. Thanks brother :-) .

Comment: let me see if I can fix the parameters so that no combination will result in anything but an increase before the peak and a decrease afterwards.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari: this information is missing in your question. Fix that.

Comment: I have fixed the parameters so that you should only get increasing before the peak and decreasing after. The peak may be very, very, weak, and far to the right, but it should be there. I lost some of the "unbalance" between the left and right slopes. There is one less parameter than before, and I haven't quite figured out how to add it back without creating the possibility of multiple peaks. I have to leave it for now, perhaps will come back to it tomorrow. You can play at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o0ja1e0c0o

Answer (score 1):

The piecewise function :
$$y(x)=\begin{cases}
a+b\:e^{c\:x}\qquad x<\chi \\
A+B\:e^{C\:x}\qquad x>\chi
\end{cases}$$
is defined on an other form :
$$y(x)=\left(a+b\:e^{c\:x}\right)H(\chi-x)+\left(A+B\:e^{C\:x}\right)H(x-\chi)$$
in which $H$ is the Heaviside step function.

If one want to avoid the picewise form one can replace the Heaviside function by a continuous function which approximates the Heaviside function. They are several possibilities.
For example a function of tbe logistic kind can be used :
$$H(X)\simeq\frac{1}{1+e^{-K\:X}}$$
$K$ is an arbitrary positive large number. Doesn't mater the value of $K$ insofar it is very large. For example :

[image]

In order to fit the equation to data one have to adjust the parameters $a,b,c,A,B,C,\chi$ using a regression method.

Since there is no scale on the graph published by the OP, arbitrary nomalized scales are added on the above graph. The values of parameters were adjusted in order to fit the blue curve to the given red points.

NOTE :

If one want a smoother transition between the two exponentials, a smaller value of $K$ has to be adjusted. So, one parameter more for the regression.

Even more general, one can introduce more paramerers such as slightly different $K_1,K_2$ and slightly different $\chi_1,\chi_2$ in order to have a wide range of possible shapes of the curve.
$$y(x)=(a+be^{cx})\frac{1}{1+e^{K_1(x-\chi_1)}} +(A+Be^{Cx})\frac{1}{1+e^{K_2(\chi_2-x)}}$$
On the other hand, a so large number of parameters $a,b,c,\chi_1,K_1,A,B,C,\chi_2,K_2$ would increases a lot the difficulty for a robust regression process. With so many parameres I doubt that the available softwares will converge to reliable result.